# Box2D dynamic body falling off screen

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, physics, box2d

I basically have a rectangular object (like a spear) and I have a ground body. The problem is, when the spear hits the ground, it doesn't bounce back, it falls though and off the screen. Here my physics setup: (Ignore the ball reference, it suppose to be called spear (rectangular))

```
-(id) init {

    if( (self=[super init])) {

        CGSize winSize = [CCDirector sharedDirector].winSize;

        self.isAccelerometerEnabled = YES;
        self.isTouchEnabled = YES;

        // Create sprite and add it to the layer
        _ball = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"SPEAR.png" rect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 10)];
        _ball.position = ccp(100, 100);
        [self addChild:_ball];

        // Create a world
        b2Vec2 gravity = b2Vec2(0.0f, -20.0f);
        bool doSleep = true;
        _world = new b2World(gravity, doSleep);

        // Create edges around the entire screen
        b2BodyDef groundBodyDef;
        groundBodyDef.position.Set(0,0);
        b2Body *groundBody = _world->CreateBody(&groundBodyDef);
        b2PolygonShape groundBox;
        b2FixtureDef boxShapeDef;
        boxShapeDef.shape = &groundBox;
        groundBox.SetAsEdge(b2Vec2(0,0), b2Vec2(winSize.width/PTM_RATIO, 0));
        groundBody->CreateFixture(&boxShapeDef);
        groundBox.SetAsEdge(b2Vec2(0,0), b2Vec2(0, winSize.height/PTM_RATIO));
        groundBody->CreateFixture(&boxShapeDef);
        groundBox.SetAsEdge(b2Vec2(0, winSize.height/PTM_RATIO), b2Vec2(winSize.width/PTM_RATIO, winSize.height/PTM_RATIO));
        groundBody->CreateFixture(&boxShapeDef);
        groundBox.SetAsEdge(b2Vec2(winSize.width/PTM_RATIO, winSize.height/PTM_RATIO), b2Vec2(winSize.width/PTM_RATIO, 0));
        groundBody->CreateFixture(&boxShapeDef);

        // Create ball body and shape
        b2BodyDef ballBodyDef;
        ballBodyDef.type = b2_dynamicBody;
        ballBodyDef.position.Set(100/PTM_RATIO, 100/PTM_RATIO);
        ballBodyDef.userData = _ball;
        b2Body *_body = _world->CreateBody(&ballBodyDef);


        b2PolygonShape spearShape;
        spearShape.SetAsBox(100/PTM_RATIO, 10/PTM_RATIO);
        b2FixtureDef ballShapeDef;
        ballShapeDef.shape = &spearShape;


        ballShapeDef.density = 1.0f;
        ballShapeDef.friction = 0.9f;
        ballShapeDef.restitution = 0.89f;

        b2Vec2 force;
        force.Set(_body->GetLinearVelocity().x+5.0f, _body->GetLinearVelocity().y+10.0f);
        _body->SetLinearVelocity(force);

        [self schedule:@selector(tick:)];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)tick:(ccTime) dt {

    _world->Step(dt, 10, 10);
    for(b2Body *b = _world->GetBodyList(); b; b=b->GetNext()) {    
        if (b->GetUserData() != NULL) {
            CCSprite *ballData = (CCSprite *)b->GetUserData();
            ballData.position = ccp(b->GetPosition().x * PTM_RATIO,
                                    b->GetPosition().y * PTM_RATIO);
            ballData.rotation = -1 * CC_RADIANS_TO_DEGREES(b->GetAngle());
        }        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't see anywhere in your code attaching the shapes to ball and to spear. If the body does not have a shape - it will not collide.

Answer (score 1):

I think only the fixtures are colliding in box2d.
But your spear has no fixture.
You only create the fixture def but not the fixture itself.

after setting restitution to you fixtureDef, add this line:

```
_body->CreateFixture(&ballShapeDef);
```

Everything should then be fine !

A bit late I know..

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used cocos2d in a while, but I remember you needed to create an space an add the objects to it, so they were aware of each other.

Answer (score 0):

Edge fixtures do not collide with each other in Box2D. Make either the ground or the spear a polygon.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I did this:  
        b2PolygonShape spearShape;
        spearShape.SetAsBox(100/PTM_RATIO, 10/PTM_RATIO);
        b2FixtureDef ballShapeDef;
        ballShapeDef.shape = &spearShape;
But still no dice.

Comment: How are you telling that the ground and the spear are colliding. You do not appear to be drawing the ground, at least in the code given. I'm not familiar with the framework you're using, can I assume that it is updating sprite position for you automatically simply because you set it as user data in a Box2D body? My guess is you have the positions of the sprite and the body in different places.

Comment: Thank again for the reply. I have updated my code to show all of it. please take a look.